# Using PWA source as hybrid app - Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

We have successfully completed our PWA with Ionic 2 and now I want to convert the same source to an Andorid Lite version (hybrid app) to publish in the Appstore.

I added the android platform as

> cordova platform add android

in my config.xml android platform version is

> AndroidManifest.xml min & max sdk version as
>   android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion=“23”

Ran my app on my android device (Mashmallow version) with

> ionic cordova run android --device

With my Android Studio I found the log as

> Expected native library version number “60.0.3112.116”, actual native
>
> library version number “60.0.3112.116” /chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(26)]
>   "service worker error : ", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/index.html (26)

I am unable to load my app and the index.html is keeps on loading and nothing is visible on the screen. Also from caniuse.com I came to know that service worker supports in android only from chrome version 61.

Can some one help me out!

regards,
Mano

Answer (score 2):

Service workers are not supported in hybrid apps because your webpage is served via the `file://` protocol and service-workers only work using the `https://` protocol. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API):

> Service workers only run over HTTPS, for security reasons. Having
>   modified network requests wide open to man in the middle attacks would
>   be really bad.

Comment: No unfortunately not as far as I know. I did some digging on this topic a few months ago myself and did not find an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need service worker in hybrid app, as all services provided by service worker could be done on app. Service workers are specific for PWA, and should be removed/hidden if build native/hybrid App.
I recommend you to read [Using Ionic/Cordova app sources as PWA](http://meumobi.github.io/ionic/pwa/2018/03/26/using-ionic-app-sources-as-pwa.html) to understand how to switch form a pwa Ionic implementation to native app, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be able to be found in play store you can wrap your app with a webview and then load the HTTPS URL of your PWA at startup. That should "solve" the issue.